# Secure place to store AuthClientSecret for a winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, azure-keyvault

I was thinking of using Azure KeyVault to store my connection string instead of App.Config

However in order to access the key vault I understand I would need to use the AuthClientSecret.

So where should I store that?  If I store it in app.config wouldn't it be like storing a key to a key?

Comment: Storing the key on end user client machine is not secure.

Comment: You could use ProtectedData https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection it uses the logged in user's credentials as the encryption key, so you can only read data in a session opened by this user. Many apps use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the key on end user client machine is not secure.

If your application directly connects to database from your client machines, then you need to use Windows Authentication. (No need to use Azure KeyVault. Instead you may want to use Azure AD).

If your application connects to a remote service like a Web API hosted on Azure App Service, you need to store the client secret of Azure Vault in Application Settings in Azure portal. Then if you need to secure data-access, again you need an authentication and authorization mechanism.

Comment: How would I store a connection string for a winforms app in Azure AD?

Comment: To use Windows Authentication, it's not necessary to create an [Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis). If you have on premises Active Directory, your client machine should join to the same active directory and login to the same domain.Also your on premises SQL Server should be joined to the same domain and allows [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017#connecting-through-windows-authentication).

Comment: What if I am using Azure SQL Server?

Comment: Then to use Windows Authentication, you need Azure AD. Take a look at [Configure and manage Azure Active Directory authentication with SQL Database, Managed Instance, or SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure). If users are logged in to the same directory, they can use active directory integrated authentication, if they are not logged in but they have a domain user name and password, then can provide the domain username and domain password to your application and use active directory password authentication.